# A simple clarification on $\#P$ closure properties

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

What does $\#P$ closure under addition and multiplication mean?

Does it mean given $NTM$s $N_1$ and $N_2$ we can create in **deterministic** polynomial time an $NTM$ $N_\times$ and $N_+$ such that for every input $x$ we have $$\#N_\times(x)=\#N_1(x)\#N_2(x)$$ $$\#N_+(x)=\#N_1(x)+\#N_2(x)$$ accepting paths?

Comment: Please don't change the question in a way that invalidates existing answers after you have already gotten a good answer to the question.  If you realize that you asked the wrong question, I suggest that you ask a new question, and  in the future be more careful about how you formulate your question and be precise about what your question is and isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's exactly what it means. Closure under addition can also be phrased as follows: if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are $\#P$ functions, then $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is also a $\#P$ function. As an exercise: How do you construct the machines $N_+$ and $N_\times$? Check that these definitions mean the same. $\#P$ has extraordinary closure properties, for example if $f\in \text{FP}$ and $p\in\#P$ then

$$\sum_{y=0}^{f(x)}p(y)$$

is also a $\#P$ function. We say that $\#P$ is **closed under exponential sums.**

In general, to say that some set $O$ is closed under an operation $\triangle$, means that if you take $a,b\in O$, then $a\triangle b\in O$. In other words, you can't "get out of $O$" by applying $\triangle$ to elements inside $O$. For example, $NP$ is closed under set intersection, because $L,K\in \text{NP}\implies L\cap K\in\text{NP}$ (why?).

Comment: @LieuweVinkhijzen If both $L,K$ have short certificates then yes instances of $L\cap K$ have short certificates. Correct?

Comment: can we think everything in deterministic polynomial time?

Comment: @777 Yes, that's right: just append the certificate of $L$ and $K$. You can think of everything in deterministic polynomial time. Then you will reason about the number of certificates this machine accepts. Otherwise you will reason about the number of accepting paths of a nondeterministic Turing Machine.

Answer (score 2):

$\# P$ is a class of functions, so it makes sense to ask whether $f,g\in \# P$ implies $f\cdot g, \hspace{1mm} f+g \in \#P$.

When attempting to prove this, we encounter the question raised in your post. Let $M_f, M_g$ be the polynomial NTMs such that $f(x)=\#M_f(x)$ and $g(x)=\#M_g(x)$. We now ask whether there exists a polynomial NTM $M$ such that for all $x\in\Sigma^*$ it holds that $\#M(x)=\#M_f(x)\cdot \# M_g(x)$. Note that nothing is said about our ability to construct $M$, although it can be easily constructed from $M_f,M_g$.

For multiplication, the machine which simulates $M_f(x)$, and in case the answer was positive (otherwise reject) simulates $M_g(x)$ and output its result satisfies the desired property. For addition, the machine which starts by non-deterministically guessing whether to compute $M_f(x)$ or $M_g(x)$ will do the trick.

Comment: your simulation argument seems to need non-determinism. My question was whether we can think everything in deterministic polynomial time.

Comment: Review the answer carefully, a function in $\# P$ is the number of accepting paths of a nondeterministc machine (what is there to count otherwise?). You asked what does it mean for $\# P$ to be closed under certain operations, the fact that the new machine uses non determinism (although it obviously has to) has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Sorry still unclear to me . I repeat I stated that 'Does it mean given $NTM$s $N_1$ and $N_2$ we can create in **deterministic** polynomial time an $NTM$ $N_\times$ and $N_+$ ...'.

Comment: As I specifically stated, it does not mean that, "nothing is said about our ability to construct $M$". That said, $M$ can be trivially constructed in deterministic linear time from $M_f,M_g$ as I have shown.

Comment: I upvoted. I know closure means that. I wanted to also ask our ability. May be I should rephrase. I have rephrased. Is it clearer with changes?

Comment: If we had two machines with total number of paths $2^k$ and $2^\ell$ where $k\neq\ell$ then our new machine has total paths not a power of $2$. Is that possibly ok (I thought total paths have to be a power of $2$)?

Comment: The number of paths doesn't have to be a power of $2$, and this might happen if the computation paths are not of the same length. However, one can easily overcome this by forcing all of the computations to be of the same length (just preform redundant operations until you reach $p(n)$ steps, where $p$ is a polynomial bounding the running time of your machine and $n$ is the input's length).